# error: cannot find -lQt5Multimedia

Tags: qt-creator, opencv

I copied a Qt project from my laptop running on ubuntu 14.04 LTS into Jetson TK1 running on 14.04.1 LTS.

And when I try to build the project its showing the following errors:

`error: cannot find -lQt5Multimedia`

`error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Can anyone help me solve these?

Comment: Is Qt5Multimedia installed?

Comment: In the ubuntu software center , `qt multimedia module` is shown as installed

Comment: Solved when I reinstalled qt after flashing JTK1 with 14.04 LTS